# How to Call AWS FHIRWORKS Patient API using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin, hl7-fhir

We are developing a Mobile App in c# xamarin which needs to call AWS FHIR Patient API to retrieve the Patient Details. We have done a setup in AWS FHIR Works API and was successful in retrieving the data in Postman using servrurl,auth url, clientid and api key. But I would like to know the implementation of the same in .net c#. Can someone give some pointers or code sample on how this implementation is acheived.

Answer (score 2):

The Firely team have a great software development kit that includes a REST API client for interacting with HL7 data from a FHIR-compliant server.  [Here is the source code](https://github.com/FirelyTeam/firely-net-sdk) for their library, and [here is a REST client example](https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-NET-SDK/client/setup.html) from their documentation.

Comment: thanks John. As I mentioned, I have AWS FHIR WORKS Setup already and need to call patient API on the same

Comment: @maheshbalasubramaniyan Firely is a client SDK that can be used with any compliant server. As far as I can tell, you should be able to use it to interact with AWS's service.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks again. I revisited the sdk documentation. I added the below Code as in the documentation in my c# project and getting the error in console.                   var client = new FhirClient("http://<My domain>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev", FhirClientSettings.CreateDefault());
                client.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization","Bearer xxx");
                client.RequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "yyy");
                Patient pat_A = client.Read<Patient>("Patient/b2c1ca50-b451-421e-92bd-5198bb244172");

Comment: Error: ExceptionSystem.InvalidOperationException: Root object has no type indication (resourceType) and therefore cannot be used to construct an FhirJsonNode. Alternatively, specify a nodeName using the parameter.

Comment: @maheshbalasubramaniyan - Would you post this error as a separate question? Then, we can get the community involved in answering it.

Comment: Hi @John, I did. here is the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946567/facing-error-in-c-sharp-applicationfirely-sdk-net?noredirect=1#comment125423850_70946567)