# Facing Error in c# Application(Firely SDK .net)

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I am creating an c# application calling AWS FHIR WORKS for which I am using the Firely SDK. I followed steps as in https://fire.ly/products/firely-net-sdk/ for Read Patient.

```
var client = new FhirClient("http://<Mydomain>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev", FhirClientSettings.CreateDefault());
                client.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization","Bearer xxx");
                client.RequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "yyy");
                Patient pat_A = client.Read<Patient>("Patient/b2c1ca50-b451-421e-92bd-5198bb244172");
                Console.WriteLine("Output" + pat_A.ToJson());
```

I am getting the following error :

```
ExceptionSystem.InvalidOperationException: Root object has no type indication (resourceType) and therefore cannot be used to construct an FhirJsonNode. Alternatively, specify a nodeName using the parameter.
   at Hl7.Fhir.Rest.TaskExtensions.WaitResult[T](Task`1 task)
   at Hl7.Fhir.Rest.BaseFhirClient.Read[TResource](String location, String ifNoneMatch, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince)
```

Can some one help me getting the issue resolved

Comment: You might get some answers if you start by including the actual HTTP response that you're getting back from the server.

Comment: I am not getting the response only. In this line , I am getting the exception and not the response.Patient pat_A = client.Read("Patient/b2c1ca50-b451-421e-92bd-5198bb244172");

Comment: The server is sending you data that does not have the required "resourceType" property in its root object.  Most likely, it's returning json data, but not FHIR (like a custom error message in json)

Comment: Hi Kramer, Could you please tell me how to capture the data as I am pretty much new to fhir and c#

Comment: Use a standard HTTP debugger

Answer (score -1):

I found that the .net client most of the times throws this generic exception. I tend to use postman with it as well and figure the error message his way and progress. But, I found HAPI implementation to be much more robust in my opinion