# How to call AWS FHIR WORKS with Firely.net SDK?

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I am calling AWS FHIR WORKS Patient API using Firely .Net SDK. While I am calling the FHIRWORKS Endpoint URL,

once I have my cognito accessToken, I am calling the API as below:

```
public static async void getPatient(string accessToken1)
        {
             var handler = new AuthorizationMessageHandler();
             handler.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken1);

            try
            {
                var client = new FhirClient("https://<DOMAIN-NAME>.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/", FhirClientSettings.CreateDefault(), handler);
                Patient p = new Patient();
                p.Id = "patientid";
                **Patient pat_A = client.Read<Patient>($"Patient/{p.Id}");**    
            }
```

I am getting the following error while calling the patient through client.Read Method. Could you please help me understand what is the issue here.
System.InvalidOperationException: Root object has no type indication (resourceType) and therefore cannot be used to construct an FhirJsonNode. Alternatively, specify a nodeName using the parameter.
at Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonNode..ctor (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject root, System.String nodeName, Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonParsingSettings settings) [0x00046] in <9de03b44cf03445584dc3ac758739635>:0
at Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonNode.ReadAsync (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.String rootName, Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonParsingSettings settings) [0x00083] in <9de03b44cf03445584dc3ac758739635>:0
at Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonNode.ParseAsync (System.String json, System.String rootName, Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonParsingSettings settings) [0x0009d] in <9de03b44cf03445584dc3ac758739635>:0
at Hl7.Fhir.Rest.EntryToTypedEntryExtensions.parseResourceAsync (System.String bodyText, System.String contentType, Hl7.Fhir.Specification.IStructureDefinitionSummaryProvider provider, System.Boolean throwOnFormatException) [0x0012b] in <31499258d6ee4ba5b9c2016903e74307>:0
at Hl7.Fhir.Rest.EntryToTypedEntryExtensions.ToTypedEntryResponseAsync (Hl7.Fhir.Rest.EntryResponse response, Hl7.Fhir.Specification.IStructureDefinitionSummaryProvider provider) [0x0013d] in <31499258d6ee4ba5b9c2016903e74307>:0
at Hl7.Fhir.Rest.TaskExtensions.WaitResult[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] task) [0x00020] in <31499258d6ee4ba5b9c2016903e74307>:0 at Hl7.Fhir.Rest.BaseFhirClient.Read[TResource] (System.String location, System.String ifNoneMatch, System.Nullable`1[T] ifModifiedSince) [0x00009] in <92e64a20fe7c4506810226d155c77f0f>:0
at MES_FHIR_App.App.getPatient (System.String accessToken1) [0x00094] in C:\Users\mahebalasubramani\source\repos\MES_FHIR_App\MES_FHIR_App\MES_FHIR_App\App.xaml.cs:96

Comment: You have already asked this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946567/facing-error-in-c-sharp-applicationfirely-sdk-net. The suggestion, like in the answer on this question, was to inspect the response, since it is not a valid FHIR json response. If you can add the details of the raw response, we might be able to help further.

Comment: Hi, Below it the stack trace :at Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonNode..ctor (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject root, System.String nodeName, Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonParsingSettings settings) [0x00046] in <9de03b44cf03445584dc3ac758739635>:0 
  at Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonNode.ReadAsync (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.String rootName, Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonParsingSettings settings) [0x00083] in <9de03b44cf03445584dc3ac758739635>:0 
  at Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.FhirJsonNode.ParseAsync (System.String json, System.String

Comment: I'm not looking for the stack trace, but for the json(?) string that comes as the response.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the json returned is not valid, there is no resourceType defined. Try to inspect the raw json returned. (You could call the endpoint with HttpClient instead of with FhirClient to get the raw json)
Could also be the url you are using is wrong in some way, wrong endpoint produces unparsable result...